# does having a header image repeated on multiple pages effect seo?

Tags: seo

I heard from someone that having a header banner image repeated on every single page makes google see it as redundant. Is this true?

Comment: Are you referring to a logo-like `img` that you specifically want indexed by (Google) image-search?

Answer (score 3):

if it's a banner you can leave it but remember to add the rel="nofollow" to the link

see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3SesBNVanGs

if it's a navigation link (like logo and homepage link) then you can see millions of web sites that have it without problems. So don't worry:)